# How to listDocuments() as a Stream of data from an Appwrite database with Flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, stream, appwrite

I am using a `StreamBuilder` to build my widget. But [`database.listDocuments()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/appwrite/latest/appwrite/Database/listDocuments.html) only returns a `Future`. Is there a way to get a stream of documents which automatically triggers a widget rebuild on a database update just as with Firebase's `snapshots()` stream?

Comment: nope, it seems that `Stream`s are not supported

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, I'm Damodar from Appwrite team
1. The Appwrite database in stable version (0.9) doesn't yet support realtime capability so there is no way to get stream there, you can use FutureBuilder and use it along with some kind of state management solution to make it work
2. As mentioned in the answer by Noodles below, realtime support is in preview version learn more about it here https://www.notion.so/Appwrite-Realtime-Sneak-Peek-c4ea0dd20d184701abe06389fc2aea01

Comment: That sounds like a perfect answer @dlohani! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this functionality is still in beta. It's called Appwrite Realtime. You can find all information about it [here](https://www.notion.so/Appwrite-Realtime-Sneak-Peek-c4ea0dd20d184701abe06389fc2aea01).